# GulpJS - how to save time by compiling only modified `js` files?

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I have integrated the `gulp` build with my `angular` application development. Each time when a `js,html,css` changes I am compiling the files as single and running the app.

in previous it was fine. when I add more `js` file I am getting delayed to reload the web page by `brower-sync`. But I understood each time `gulp` is compiling all files are single even if that's not updated.

my question is:

1. how to compile only `updated` files and run the `brower-sync` ? here is my gulp code :

`gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(annotate())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});`

[my full gulp code is here](https://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/5Lnpkd3b/)

Answer (score -1):

Use [`gulp-changed`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed).

```
var changed = require('gulp-changed');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(changed('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(annotate())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

Comment: It may help when we compress the files with their own names. when we concat as single file it won't help.

Comment: Since you `concat` before other tasks, doesn't it need to compile the whole `scripts.js` every time there are changes in any of the source files? Maybe move `annotate` and `uglify` before the `concat` ?